# the fits of political violence

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

> I’m trying to understand why committee members are not gripped by these realities. After more than a century of relative democratic stability maybe it’s hard for some people to imagine precisely how the **fits** of political violence that bedevil other nations could hit our shores. Maybe the committee members are imprisoned in the categories set by past investigation committees — Watergate and 9/11. (David Brooks)

The word **fit** reads in on-line Oxford Dictionary:

> The particular way in which something, especially a garment or component, fits.

I don't understand what *fits of political violence* means in the context.

Comment: The word fit has more than one meaning. Google "define:fit". Please incorporate a link into your citation of the Oxford Dictionary.

Comment: I did a quick Google of 'fit meaning Oxford' and chose the [first result I got](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/fit_1). To my surprise, it doesn't even mention the noun form  that Michael gives in his answer (which is the form and meaning intended in your example). So, if you happen to be using www.oxfordlearners.com as your dictionary, you might want to consider switching to something else.

Comment: @tkp the first meaning cited in a dictionary does not mean it is the  most important. Words have more than one meaning, they can be verbs, adjectives and nouns. The noun form which is mentioned in Michael's answer is included but it's under *noun*,  look to the right-hand side for the link. Moreover, the OP's definition appears to come from Lexico not the OALD.

Comment: Under [**fit 2**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/fit#h367360) we have: "*A sudden attack of convulsions and/or loss of consciousness, typical of epilepsy and some other medical conditions.*"

Answer (score 2):

Fit is a verb, but also a noun. Fits of political violence are sudden outbreaks of political violence. See meaning (2) below.

> **Fit (noun)**
>
> **1 an uncontrolled expression of strong emotion**
> *He threw a fit [=he became very angry and upset] when they accused him
> of cheating.
>
> She has/throws a fit [=tantrum] when she doesn't get
> what she wants.*
>
> **2 a sudden occurrence of some activity, emotion, etc.**
> *a fit of anger
>
> a fit of coughing = a coughing fit
>
> He apologized profusely in a fit of remorse.
>
> The joke sent the audience into fits of laughter. [=it made
> the people in the audience laugh a lot]*
>
> **3 an abnormal state in which you become unconscious and your body
> moves in an uncontrolled and violent way**
> *an epileptic fit [=(more commonly) seizure]*

[Fit (noun) - Britannica Dictionary](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/fit)

Comment: My Glasgow friend said her father 'threw an epi' when she came home drunk one Saturday night as a teenager.

Comment: I think "  the  fits of political violence" can be translated into a lot of politcal violence, by the  help of the dictionary.

Comment: @Mankak - the essence is that the occurrences or outbreaks of political violence are sudden, not that they are necessarily large.